# Show and PlotLegend row spacing

Tags: plotting, legending

In this toy example I make some plots, each with a legend, and combine them with Show. All the legends are assembled into a column which is helpful but it is too high for the size of plot. How can I make the row spacing in the column smaller?

```
plots = Table[
   Plot[x i, {x, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle -> {Hue[i/11]},
    PlotLegends -> 
     LineLegend[{"Serial " <> ToString[i]}, 
      LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 10}],
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
    ImageSize -> 4 72,
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}],
   {i, 10}
   ];
Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2:** Post-processing `plots` without having to create a new legend:

```
Legended[Show[plots[[;; , 1]], PlotRange -> All], 
 Column[Join @@ plots[[;; , 2, All, 1]], Spacings -> -.8]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Legended[Show[plots[[;; , 1]], PlotRange -> All],
 Placed[Column[Join @@ plots[[;; , 2, All, 1]], Spacings -> -.8], {Before, Top}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

Use the  (afaik) undocumented option `"Spacings"` for `LineLegend`:

```
legend = LineLegend[Hue[#/11] & /@ Range[10], ("Serial " <> ToString[#]) & /@ Range[10],
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 10},
   "Spacings" -> {1, .2}]
```

or use `LegendLayout` with a custom layout function:

```
legend = LineLegend[Hue[#/11] & /@ Range[10], ("Serial " <> ToString[#]) & /@ Range[10],
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 10}, 
  LegendLayout -> (Grid[#, Spacings -> {1, .2}] &)]
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then use  `legend` with `Legended`

```
Legended[Plot[(# x) & /@ Range[10], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> (Hue[#/11] & /@ Range[10]), Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 4 72, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}], legend]
```

or with `PlotLegends`

```
Plot[(# x) & /@ Range[10], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> (Hue[#/11] & /@ Range[10]), Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 4 72, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

we get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** If you do not want to redo the `Plot`s you can use your `plots` with `legend` as follows:

```
Legended[Show[plots[[;;, 1]], PlotRange -> All], legend]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Hugh, thought the question was about _legend row spacings_, no?:)

Comment: Yes it was and you answered it directly. What I have done is to take his method of reconstructing and then use your spacings method. Perhaps I will give you the credit after all.

Comment: @Hugh, i did not mean to suggest that you re-consider your accept decision. You should feel free to accept any answer that you find most useful.

Comment: You were correct to point out that spacings is the issue. You answered that and should get the credit. However, xslittlegrass idea of reconstructing was also helpful but did not deal with spacing.

Comment: The answer is getting  better and better. Unfortunately I cannot keep giving you more and more upvotes. Thanks for your continued help.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, you may not want to reconstruct the legend from scratch then you can extract the legends from the plots, and make adjustments on them, for example

```
p=Show[plots, PlotRange -> All];

opt = First@Cases[plots[[1]], LineLegend[x_List, y_List, opt__] :> {opt}, ∞];

lgd = LineLegend[
  Sequence @@ 
   Transpose[
    First@Cases[#, 
        LineLegend[x_List, y_List, opt__] :> {x, y}, ∞] & /@
      plots], Sequence @@ FilterRules[opt, Except[LegendLayout]], 
  LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}]

Legended[First@Cases[p, Graphics[___], ∞], lgd]
```

[image]

Or

```
lgd = LineLegend[
  Sequence @@ 
   Transpose[
    First@Cases[#, 
        LineLegend[x_List, y_List, opt__] :> {x, y}, ∞] & /@
      plots], Sequence @@ FilterRules[opt, Except[LegendLayout]], 
  LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}]

Legended[First@Cases[p, Graphics[___], ∞], Placed[lgd, Bottom]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like not having to reconstruct. I think you may have defined p = Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]. Legended seems to be the way forward.

Comment: Right, I have corrected that.

Comment: Sorry I can't select your answer. Your method of reconstructing is good but the question is about spacing. So really kglr should get the credit. Pity I can't give it to both of you. I have used your method of reconstructing.

Comment: No worry! I just want to share this, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

The option [`LegendMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMargins.html) can be used to significantly reduce the spacing.

This option can be added directly to `LineLegend`

```
plots = Table[
   Plot[x i, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Hue[i/11]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     LineLegend[{"Serial " <> ToString[i]}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 10}, 
      LegendMargins -> {0, 0}], 
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 4 72, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}], {i, 10}];
Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot1]

or after the `plots` were produced.

```
plots = Table[
   Plot[x i, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Hue[i/11]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     LineLegend[{"Serial " <> ToString[i]}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 10}], 
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 4 72, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}], {i, 10}];
Show[plots /. LineLegend[ll__] :> LineLegend[ll, LegendMargins -> {0, 0}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot2]

To have the legends starting at the top, one additional replacement is needed.

```
Show[plots /. 
   LineLegend[ll__] :> LineLegend[ll, LegendMargins -> {0, 0}] /. After -> {After, Top}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot3]

Negative margin values reduce the spacing even further.

```
Show[plots /. LineLegend[ll__] :> LineLegend[ll, LegendMargins -> {{5, 0}, {-5, -5}}] /. 
  After -> {After, Top}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot4]

Comment: Another very helpful approach. It seems that there is more available than I thought or could find. Thanks